# Random Number Generator in oracle 11g by SQL or Stored procedure without DBMS.RANDOM

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I want to generate random Numbers in Oracle 11g. But due to client request, I cannot use `dbms_random.random` of Oracle.

Is there any other way I can generate random numbers?

Duplication are strictly not allowed, numbers should be of length 4

```
0001
0053
9871
0098
0003
```

If any other Oracle library from which I can generate, then suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please explain why you cannot use `dbms_randomrandom()`.  That does not seem like a reasonable limitation.

Comment: Client Has Said not to use it .. And you know client/Customer is the real boss :)

Comment: Thats why i mentioned it in my question .. if there is any other way then it will be a real help for me !!

Comment: Without knowing the reason why, it is impossible to say if another solution would meet the requirement.

Comment: Sir , I want a solution , if there is any solution then ur help will be appreciated ..

Comment: Oracle has sys_guid which gives a unique sequence of symbols for each call, but its length is much more than 4. So in general it's not possible. But you can write your own function + a table to keep track of the used numbers.

Comment: I can substr the length so it wont be an issue ..

Comment: Can u plz tell me how should i use it sir ...

Comment: If you substr it may not by unique any more + there can be letters

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select a four digit number without duplication, you can start by creating a table of numbers from 0 to 9999:

```
create table numbers as 
    select level - 1 as seqnum
    from dual
    connect by level <= 10000;
```

Then order this randomly and choose however many non-repeating numbers you want.  Up to 10,000 of course.  I think this will work:

```
with random as (
      select to_char(n.seqnum, '0000') as val, row_number() over (order by sys_guid) as seqnum
      from numbers
     )
select *
from random
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Comment: I'll do convey this to my managers .. and will come back to you if i need more assistance in this regard :)

Comment: Because from the look of it .. i think this is the ONLY solution to my question besides dbms_random ( which is not required ) ..

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use dbms_random and your number must be distinct you can use pure sequence with a little help of "Fermat's little theorem".

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Simply use sequence number, put into the formula and you get "semi-random" unique number.
Search wikipedia about "Discrete logarithm". The same principle is also used for OTP (one time passwords), if the sequence number is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

u can use milliseconds from SYSTIMESTAMP

```
select to_char(systimestamp,'ff')/1000 from dual
```